# Reading address on the stack returns 0 instead of 00400018 in MIPS

Tags: stack, mips

I am trying to make a recursive multiplication function in MIPS. The logic is :

We want to multiply x by y.

Base case : x = 0, return y

General case : x != 0, return y + (x-1)*y

So I wrote the code, and everything works fine as expected, except for one little bit. At the beginning of the code, I do :

```
    # save the first address from $ra on the stack so that we can come back and exit
    sw $ra 0($sp)
    addi $sp $sp -4

    jal recursive_multiplication

    # get the last address on the stack for the last jr $ra to exit
    lw $ra 0($sp)
    addi $sp $sp 4
```

And that should store the very first address from $ra on the stack, the very first address being 00400018, the line after the "hidden" *jal main* from the initialization of the code. After putting it on the stack and doing my business, I can come back and read it, and end my code with a *jr $ra* and terminate the process. The issue is : when I read the address on the stack, I get 0, instead of 00400018.  Also, I noticed that everytime I put an address on the stack, the stack gets added something that looks like this :

```
| . @ .
```

And the whole stack goes from this  :

```
[7ffff6b0]    00000001  7ffff777  00000000  7fffffe1    . . . . w . . . . . . . . . . .
```

To this :

```
[7ffff698]    0040007c  0040007c                        | . @ . | . @ . 
[7ffff6a0]    0040007c  0040007c  0040003c  00000000    | . @ . | . @ . < . @ . . . . . 
[7ffff6b0]    00400018  7ffff777  00000000  7fffffe1    . . @ . w . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Of course, I'm only including the interesting part of the user stack. The rest of it isn't accessed nor modified by my code.

I have a feeling that the error comes from the fact that between the last two @'s, there are 7 dots instead of the regular 2 and a "|" , which causes the reading to return 0 to $ra (since it reads "a dot"), but I can't really wrap my head around it.

Any idea why this is happening ? Thanks for reading !

Comment: You should be able to see the issue using the debugger and single stepping.  Watch each instruction, and observe what/when registers and/or memory changes after each instruction.  You'll be able to see that the load is going to a different address than the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push operation should pre-decrement the stack pointer. That is, instead of:

```
sw $ra 0($sp)
addi $sp $sp -4
```

you should do:

```
addi $sp $sp -4
sw $ra 0($sp)
```

Comment: Thank you !! I'd been stuck on this for over an hour now, I felt like it was such a tiny mistake but couldn't find it. Thanks a lot for the help, marking it as solution.